# Setting up a loop to detect keypress in discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I am trying to use keypress detection in my code these days and it seems hard to push a keypress detection function to the discord.py bot loop function

Apparently this is what I have been trying to do

```
    import pyscreenshot as ps
    import keyboard
    from PIL import Image
    from discord.ext import commands
    client=commands.Bot("!")
    async def keypress_detector():
        while True:
            try:  
                if keyboard.is_pressed('['):#if key '[' is pressed 
                    im=ps.grab()
                    im.save("screenie.png")
                    image_obj = Image.open("screenie.png")
                    cropped_image = image_obj.crop((130, 445, 580, 812))
                    cropped_image.save("updated.png")
                    await client.send_file(client.get_channel('id-here'), "updated.png")
                else:
                    pass
            except Exception as ex:
                return print(str(ex))
    if __name__ == "__main__":
       client.loop.create_task(keypress_detector())   
       client.run("TOKEN")
```

The function works pretty well if i just want to run it normally(outside the bot loop, although it doesnt send the screenshot to the channel), i want the bot to send a screenshot to the chat when i press a certain key. If there is any other way, please tell me.

UPDATE

Got it fixed, didnt work for the first few times but now it does.

Comment: @DankerCoder Do you mind posting your solution because I have been struggling with this as well.

Comment: @rominoushana the solution is the same as the code in my question, you'll add a background task to your bot that listens to the keyboard

Answer (score 0):

Due to `while True` causing an infinite loop that is not asynchronous (discord.py relies on this) you will run into problems. I'm not sure if what you are trying to achieve is actually possible in the realms of python, or any language for that matter. I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve here either, none the less correct me if you know I'm wrong.